# Change data show SQL

Tags: sql

I have this script

```
select 'clos' as name, COUNT(clos.ticket_cp) as counte 
from clos 
union all 
select 'encour',COUNT(en_cours.ticket_cp)   
from en_cours  
union all 
select 'gele',COUNT(gele.ticket_cp) as gele  
from gele
```

and it returns a result like this:

```
encours  15
gele     10
clos     14
```

Is there any way to make it look like this

```
Name        encours  gele  clos
Nombre        15      10    14
```

Comment: you are looking for PIVOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subqueries in the `select`:

```
select (select COUNT(clos.ticket_cp) as counte from clos) as clos,
       (select COUNT(en_cours.ticket_cp) from en_cours) as en_cours,
       (select COUNT(gele.ticket_cp) from gele) as gele
```

This will work in most databases.  Some require a `from` clause, such as `from dual` or `from sysibm.dummy1`.

Comment: it's work thanks but i don't want name and number to show up , i say it just for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try `PIVOT`

```
SELECT 'Nombre' as name,*
( 
   SELECT 'clos' AS name, COUNT(clos.ticket_cp) AS Counte FROM clos 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'encour', COUNT(en_cours.ticket_cp) AS Counte FROM en_cours 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'gele', COUNT(gele.ticket_cp) AS Counte FROM gele
)X
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Counte) FOR name IN ([clos], [encour], [gele])
) AS pivot_table;
```